# Password management in Azure AD B2C Free Tier

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to reset or change a user's password in Azure AD B2C Free Tier?  If so, is there an example of how to do that?

[This page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/active-directory/) seems to indicate that this is only available as paid options.

Comment: The page you link is for Azure AD, not B2C. These are two different products, related, but different :)

Comment: B2C allows users to reset their password by themselves if you enable the policy for that and configure it in your app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-password-reset-policy

Comment: Wow, that's great - thank you for pointing that out. I was getting the feeling that the authentication options were a lot more confusing than the rest of Azure's offerings.  Do you want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B2C is a separate service from Azure AD (though it runs on top of Azure AD).
The page you linked is for Azure AD, not B2C.

B2C allows users to reset their password by themselves if you enable the policy for that and configure it in your app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-password-reset-policy.

You can find pricing for B2C here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory-b2c/